# How can I clean memory or use SageMaker instead to avoid MemoryError: Unable to allocate for an array with shape (25000, 2000) and data type float64

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using keras to train a model on SageMaker, here's the code I'm using but I hit the error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 381. MiB for an array with shape (25000, 2000) 
    and data type float64
```

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras import models, layers, optimizers, losses, metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load imbd preprocessed dataset
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(
    num_words=2000)

# one-hot encoding all the integer into a binary matrix
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=2000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))        
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.                          
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)                  
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
```

Then I get the error.

The first time when I run this code it works but it failed when I tried to re-run it, how I can fix it by cleaning the memory or is there a way that I can use the memory on SageMaker?

Comment: Did you increase the size of your EC2 sagemaker instance? Here is a list of options https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/ -- the default instance won't have much memory.

Comment: @MarcMaxmeister Hey I didn't increase the EC2 size, I'm still using free tier... Restart the kernel and rerun the codes seem can solve this issue.

Comment: Okay good. For my problem yesterday I had to restart with a ml.12xlarge instance (192GB ram), then it worked. This only costs $4/hour and it was done in less than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't know about SageMaker or AWS specifically, but something you can do is cast your input to `float32`, which takes less memory space. You can cast it like this:

```
train_data = tf.cast(train_data, tf.float32)
```

`float32` is the default value of Tensorflow weights so you don't need `float64` anyway. Proof:

```
import tensorflow as tf
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)
print(layer(tf.random.uniform((10, 100), 0, 1)).dtype)
```

```
<dtype: 'float32'>
```

My other suggestions are to get less words from your dataset, or to not one-hot encode them. If you're planning on training a recurrent model with an embedding layer, you won't need to anyway.